# "service cannot be activated because it requires asp net compatibility", but I need it for impersonation

Tags: c#, asp.net, wcf, iis-7, impersonation

I posted a question yesterday about how to enable impersonation using WCF services here: [WCF service not impersonating specified user in config?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5172840/wcf-service-not-impersonating-specified-user-in-config)

I enabled aspnetCompatibilityMode but when I update my service proxy, it says "the service cannot be activated because it requires asp net compatibility". I'm not entirely sure what this means. If I change the setting to AspNetCompatibilityRequirementsMode.Allowed, it doesn't enable impersonation. I tried enabling the setting in both the web.config as well as via the class attribute.

Is there a way around this without setting my service's app pool to run as the user I need? Thanks.

Comment: Have you enabled compatibility mode in your web.config as well?

Comment: I have not done both. I have either enabled it in the service's web.config or on the class itself (I have not changed anything in my site's web.config).

Answer (score 16, accepted):

You must turn on AspNetCompatibility in web.config of site hosting your service:

```
<system.serviceModel>
  ...
  <serviceHostingEnvironment aspNetCompatibilityEnabled="true"/>
</system.serviceModel>
```

Because you are making your service implementation dependent on ASP.NET you should mark your service class with:

```
[AspNetCompatibilityRequirements(RequirementsMode = AspNetCompatibilityRequirementsMode.Required)]
```

Default value of `AspNetCompatibilityRequirements.RequirementMode` is `NotAllowed` so that is most probably reason for your exception.